# audio tag facebook app browser io6 vs ios7

Tags: facebook, html5-audio

In the facebook app's browser on a device running ios6, this audio element plays as expected:

```
<audio controls><source src="http://444d4cdc0b6bf5f591a8-06afc691eed7093ada55d9385ed988db.r31.cf1.rackcdn.com/01%20Flame.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">Your browser does not support this audio format.</audio>
```

However when running ios7, this same element does not play as expected. We tested this on iphones and ipads, running ios6 and ios7 using the most recent version of the facebook app (6.5) on each device. Here is a jsfiddle with the audio element above - http://jsfiddle.net/mpenfield/r7MgY/21121/

To replicate, insert the jsfiddle link in a facebook message, then open the link from the facebook app. If you are running ios6 it should play, ios7 won't. Does anyone know a workaround for this that does not involve audio/vnd.facebook.bridge? Thanks!

Comment: I'm seeing audio issues on http://tarheelreader.org. Sounds play on iOS6 and earlier but not on iOS7 when running in App mode. They still play running with the usual Safari interface.